# Convert Text String Into VBA Statement/Object

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a bunch of dictionaries in VBA; the best solution is to concatenate prefix "dict" with a string variable (enumeration would cause more complexities). Is there a way to convert a string into a VBA statement?

For example, I have a dictionary `dictABC` created. How to refer to it by using two segment of strings, `"dict"` and `"ABC"` concatenated?

(The only way I could think of is to create a "meta-dictionary", with pairs of string `"dictABC"` and dictionary `dictABC`.)

Comment: VBA doesn't support this functionality. At an absolute stretch, you could wrap the code in a Sub and call it by building a string value as the argument in `Application.Run()`

Comment: It can be implemented with just nested dictionaries. Top level dictionary has the strings `dictABC`, `dictDEF`, ... , `dictXYZ` as keys, and created sub dictionaries as values.

Answer (score 1):

If you build an array of dictionary objects and use another single dictionary to act as the index of all of the dictionaries you've created, you should get something akin to what you have described. Consider the following data that has three unique values in Col A.

```
Col A    Col B      Col C      Col D
Y        196        RNT        4-Jan-2015
Y        127        IYI        12-Feb-2015
X        173        ZVM        24-Jan-2015
Z        124        LRP        16-Jan-2015
Z        176        XTN        27-Jan-2015
Y        137        SUG        30-Jan-2015
X        139        IBG        7-Feb-2015
X        165        DON        11-Feb-2015
Z        153        EUU        16-Feb-2015
```

After adding Microsoft Scripting Runtime to the VBE's Tools ► References we can run down column A, adding a key entry and index number to the index of dictionaries then redimming the array of dictionaries for room and populating that new dictionary object. If a value in column A already exists, the dNDX is used to figure out which dictionary object in the array should be referenced and adds a new key/item.

```
Sub mcr_Dict_Over_Dicts()
    Dim rw As Long, d As Long, sCOLa As String, ky As Variant
    Dim dNDX As New Scripting.Dictionary, dDICTs() As New Scripting.Dictionary

    dNDX.CompareMode = TextCompare 'or BinaryCompare
    With ActiveSheet
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            sCOLa = .Cells(rw, 1).Value
            If CBool(Len(sCOLa)) Then
                If Not dNDX.Exists(sCOLa) Then
                    'create a new entry in dNDX and a new dictionary in the array
                    d = dNDX.Count + 1
                    dNDX.Add Key:=sCOLa, Item:=d
                    ReDim Preserve dDICTs(1 To d)
                    dDICTs(d).Add Key:=.Cells(rw, 2).Text, _
                      Item:=Join(Array(.Cells(rw, 1).Text, .Cells(rw, 2).Text, .Cells(rw, 3).Text, .Cells(rw, 4).Text), ChrW(8203))
                Else
                    'add an entry to an existing dictionary
                    dDICTs(dNDX.Item(sCOLa)).Add Key:=.Cells(rw, 2).Text, _
                      Item:=Join(Array(.Cells(rw, 1).Text, .Cells(rw, 2).Text, .Cells(rw, 3).Text, .Cells(rw, 4).Text), ChrW(8203))
                End If
            End If
        Next rw

        'return the values to the worksheet reordered in an alternate location
        .Cells(1, 6).Resize(1, 4) = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value
        For d = LBound(dDICTs) To UBound(dDICTs)
            For Each ky In dDICTs(d)
                .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 4) _
                  = Split(dDICTs(d).Item(ky), ChrW(8203))
            Next ky
        Next d

    End With


    For d = LBound(dDICTs) To UBound(dDICTs)
        dDICTs(d).RemoveAll
    Next d
    'alternately redim dDICTs
    ReDim dDICTs(1)

    dNDX.RemoveAll
    Set dNDX = Nothing
End Sub
```

This does demand that there will be some value or combination of values (hash) that can be used as a unique key within each of the dictionaries in the array.

[image: Dictionary of Array Dictionaries]

Note that the results in columns G and I are text based. This is a result of them being split out of a concatenated string.

Comment: @lovechillcool - Looked at your profile page but couldn't immediately see any reference to 'meta-dictionary' method. Is it similar to what I've proposed in this thread above?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. What it mean by meta-dictionary is that you create a dictionary of dictionary. The key will be string "dictABC" and the item is dictionary dictABC.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused why you've thought of and for some reason rejected the simple, obvious solution.

But if you really want to go the code generation route, this is how you would do it.

```
Function dictAbcd() As Object
    Static result As Object
    If result Is Nothing Then
        Set result = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End If
    Set dictAbcd = result
End Function

Public Sub Test()
    Dim x As Object
    Dim dict_index As String

    dictAbcd("key") = "value"

    dict_index = "Abcd"

    Set x = Application.Run("dict" & dict_index)

    Debug.Print x("key") ' Prints "value"
End Sub
```

N.b. doing it this way is completely ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the dictionaries into a collection, which allows you to have a string index.